# Can't open xls with python "AssertionError"

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xls, xlrd

I'm trying to open an xls file from a site and I can't open, when i download in my local machine it opens fine with LibreOffice.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

resp = requests.get('https://www.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/cidade/secretarias/upload/02FEV2021.xls')
with open('test1.xls', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(resp.content)

pd.read_excel('/content/test1.xls')
```

AssertionError

Tried with openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook('/content/test1.xls')
```

Error: InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support the old .xls file format, please use xlrd to read this file, or convert it to the more recent .xlsx file format.

And with xlrd

```
import xlrd
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('/content/test1.xls')
```

AssertionError

Comment: Please show us the whole error message

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/xlrd/compdoc.py in _locate_stream(self, mem, base, sat, sec_size, start_sid, expected_stream_size, qname, seen_id)
    447             s = sat[s]
    448         assert s == EOCSID
--> 449         assert tot_found == found_limit
    450         # print >> self.logfile, "_locate_stream(%s): seen" % qname; dump_list(self.seen, 20, self.logfile)
    451         if not slices:

AssertionError:

Comment: Don't add additional information like code and error messages etc in comments. Edit/update your question.

Comment: Looks like the file is invalid.